# WPF fill Listbox with collection member property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am working on list of Recipes showed in some sort of list in my WPF app.
I have a collection of recipes

```
public Cookbook()
{
   RecipeList=new ObservableCollection<Recipe>();
   AddRecipe(new Recipe("Food1", 0, null));
}
```

each recipe has property called Name.`public string Name { get; set; }`

What i am doing now is that i populate list with this collection

```
<ListView x:Name="CategoriesListBox" Margin="10,0,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeList}"
        Loaded="CategoriesListBox_OnLoaded" 
        SelectionChanged="CategoriesListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.DataContext>
           <Implementation:Cookbook/>
        </ListBox.DataContext>
</ListView>
```

Which of course results into list populated with object names - i want recipe names in the list. Is there any way to show property Name in Listbox instead?

*(I am looking for XAML solution - no code behind)*

// I already tried ListView and nested Gridview as a solution - this works but this also creates unnecesary grid and header fields on the top.

```
<ListView x:Name="CategoriesListBox" Margin="10,0,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeList}"
    Loaded="CategoriesListBox_OnLoaded" 
    SelectionChanged="CategoriesListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.DataContext>
        <Implementation:Cookbook/>
    </ListBox.DataContext>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the ListView.
Set it to `Name`

`DisplayMemberPath="Name"`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use a ListBox instead of a ListView, and set its `DisplayMemberPath` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" .../>
```

Or set its `ItemTemplate` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeList}" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```